# # vs $ when documenting code in articles

Tags: linux, documentation, command-line-interface

I have looked and haven't found the answer to the question why some websites use # before each line of code and others use $. I am specifically referring to say, the process of compiling a linux kernel using the following page: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/?utm_source=feedly&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+TheGeekStuff+(The+Geek+Stuff)

The first step is changing the user directory:

"# cd /usr/src/"

The last step in the process is verifying installation

"$ uname -r"

Both are issuing a command to perform (changing directories and verifying version number) but I am not sure why the pound is used in one pace whereas the dollar sign is used in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # symbol implies you are running the commands as root. Usually the $ sign implies you are running the commands as a normal user.

The reason why the symbol changes suddenly in the example you provided is that the user is rebooting the computer. So, the first commands are run as root (superuser) and then the restart happens - after the restart the user is no longer root, only a simple user (they need to run su again in order to become root)